# Euer and Deine. Difference?

Tags: word-usage

I'm using DuoLingo app, and it is confusing me slightly with numerous problems, currently this one: Both *deine* and *euer* mean "your", but it isn't clear in which context either should be used. Can anyone put these in a sentence for context?

Comment: Did you consult Wiktionary? Why not?

Comment: Was not aware of Wiktionary. I googled both and got 'your'.

Answer (score 2):

It's about singular and plural. I give you an example:

Asking one person:

> Tom, ist das **deine**<sub>singular</sub> Katze?
>   Tom, is this **your**<sub>singular</sub> cat?

Asking two or more persons:

> Tom und Lisa, ist das **eure**<sub>plural</sub> Katze?
>   Tom and Lisa, is this **your**<sub>plural</sub> cat?